# sh: 1: less: not found when using PSQL commands

Tags: postgresql, psql

I installed Postgres and I'm using the psql tool. Some queries work fine, like `SELECT current_date;` and `SELECT 2 + 2;`. But others like `\h` throw an error `sh: 1: less: not found`, queries like `SELECT * FROM foo` also throw this error. I didn't find anything reporting this error neither in the docs or other forums. What could it be?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and postgres 14.5

Comment: The system pager is not being picked up. At the OS command line what does `l /etc/alternatives/pager` return? Add as update to question.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver, thanks for your attention. I already fixed it! Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it. I messed my PATH variable when I added a shortcut to the postgres bin files.

My PATH variable was written in `.bashrc` like this:

```
# Set environment PATH for postgres 14
PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/"
```

What fixed was rewrite to:

```
# Set environment PATH for postgres 14
export PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/:$PATH"
```

Hope it helps someone some day.